# How to save CSV in database of Django?

Tags: python, django, csv

I made a logic to download the CSV file but now I also want to save it in the database.

I have tried to save that by the file name but that doesn't work

```
def index(request):
if request.method == "POST":

    url  = request.POST.get('url', '')
    username = request.POST.get('username','')


    r = requests.get(url)           
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="lxml")    
    p_name = soup.find_all("h2",attrs={"class": "a-size-mini"})
    p_price = soup.find_all("span",attrs={"class": "a-price-whole"})

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="product_file.csv"'

    for name,price in zip(p_name,p_price):
        writer = csv.writer(response)
        writer.writerow([name.text, price.text])

    return response
    csv_file =  csv.writer(response)   
    csv_save =  csv_save(url=url,username=username,csv_file=csv_file)
    csv_save.save

return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: you have wrong indentations and it is hard to say if you try to run code afer `return response` which will be never executed.

Comment: @furas so what is the possible way to save the file in the database and download it at the same the time

Comment: use `return` as last command because it ends function.

Comment: I did that but got this error "local variable 'csv_save' referenced before assignment" can you please show me some codes how can I complete this task

Comment: what is `csv_save(...)` ? What do you try to do with this function which you didn't create? Or maybe it is database model ? Did you create this model in Django ?

Comment: this is model class name

Comment: did you create this model? Did you import this model to this script ?

Comment: BTW: don't do `csv_save = csv_save(...)` because this way you can loose access to your model and you can't use it again.

Comment: so how can I download and save this file at the same time?

Comment: first you have to import model to this script. It seems you didn't do this. Or it has differne name then `csv_save`. Maybe add all code in question - with imports and file with models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say the csv file contains: username, title, interests. You can save the data in your database using a model with the same fields in your models.py file:

```
class FromCsv(models.Model):    
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    interests = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

You'd then need to iterate over the rows of the csv file, store its data in variables and save the objects using your view by doing this for each iteration:

```
FromCsv.objects.create(username=csvusername, title=csvtitle, interests=csvinterests)
```

Since it looks like you want to actually save the csv file you could have a FileField on your model and do something like this:

```
FromCsv.objects.create(url=url, username=username, csv_file=File(csv_file))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    csv_file = csv.writer(response)
    # the object created by calling csv_save can't have the same variable name
    # so we'll call it csv_save_obj to denote it's an instance of csv_save
    csv_save_obj = csv_save(url=url,username=username,csv_file=csv_file)
    # remember to add parenthesis when calling save
    csv_save_obj.save()

    # this needs to be at the end, because code after it won't execute
    return response
```

Comment: Thanks but this method is returning an error "'_csv.writer' object has no attribute '_committed'"